# What is GSList* in Java-DBus?

Tags: java, dbus, libpurple

how can I create a method in a [`DBusInterface`](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-java/api/org/freedesktop/dbus/DBusInterface.html) for [`purple_find_buddies`](http://developer.pidgin.im/doxygen/dev/html/blist_8h.html#ec109120497bd9168a618e55cf1c1907)? Specifically, what do I have to specify as the return type instead of `GSList*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems, it simply becomes a `List` - in this case, a `List<Integer>`.

```
public List<Integer> PurpleFindBuddies(int account, String name);
```

This line belongs to a file that `CreateInterface` generated for me:

```
CreateInterface im.pidgin.purple.PurpleService /im/pidgin/purple/PurpleObject -f
```